# Upload byte array from android to java server?

Tags: android, upload, java-server

I am working on an Android application in which i have to upload byte array to java server. The byte array size will be 1024 bytes(1k). Which is the recommended way to upload data from android to server ?

Comment: HTTPS would work well in this case.